# How do I make it so my bot doesn't send "role given" when it doesn't give the role?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So I made this command called `q!giverole` where it gives a role to the person who uses it, when the role is given the bot says "role given" but when someone already has the role and uses it I want it to send something like "you already have that role", but instead of sending "you already have that role" it sends "role given", so how do I make it so it only sends "you already have that role" when someone already has the role? this is the code anyway:

```
if(message.content.startsWith("q!giverole"))
var role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "example");
        message.member.roles.add(role);
           message.channel.send("Role given!")
        
        if(role == true)
        message.channel.send("you already have that role")
    }
```

I also tried:

```
 if(message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "example"))
```

But in that case the bot just sends both "role given" and "you already have that role". I'm very new to `discord.js` and `javascript` so I hope you can help me

Comment: try this  `if(role === true)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use `<message>.member.roles.cache.has()`

```
if(message.content.startsWith("q!giverole")) {
    const role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "example");
    if (!role) return message.channel.send('role doesnt exist :(');
    if (message.member.roles.cache.has(role.id) return message.channel.send("You already have that role :)");
    message.member.roles.add(role);
    message.channel.send("Role given yeee")
}
```

Comment: @TomTheItalianBBQ i gotchu bud :D

Answer (score 0):

Role is the index of the first occurence of the role name so will return an index (a number I think). You can check if role isn't undefined as a way of checking if the role exists. [see here for more information on .find](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_find.asp)

As for sending only one I'd use an if else statement:

```
if(message.content.startsWith("q!giverole")) {
    var role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "example");
    if (message.member.roles.find(role => role.name === "example") !== undefined) {
        message.channel.send("You already have that role")
    } else if (role !== undefined) {
        message.member.roles.add(role);
        message.channel.send("Role given!")
    } else {
        message.channel.send("Role doesn't exist)
    }
}
```

Also you don't need the `== true` when checking if a boolean value is true:

```
if (bool) {
    //runs if bool is true
} else if (!bool) {
    //runs if bool is false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the role boolean to true after send the msg 'Role given!'

Comment: as i said i'm very new to js/discord,js, so, how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code to give a role to a user:

```js
client.on('message', msg => {
if(msg.content.startsWith('`commandname`')) {
const role = msg.guild.roles.cache.get('`id`')
//^or you can use the find method^
if(!msg.member.roles.has(role)) {
msg.member.roles.add(role).catch(err => {return console.log('An error occurred: ' + err});
msg.channel.send(`Role ${role.name} has been added`)
} else if(msg.member.roles.has(role)) {
return msg.channel.send('You already have that role!');
}
}
})
```

Sorry if there are errors, I couldn't get time to test it.